# Spark / Databricks Code not recognizing date field error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am querying a col in a spark dataframe which I have converted to datetype as follows:

SAlesByCountry2 = SAlesByCountry.withColumn("SaleDate", current_date())

It has converted successfully see following:

```
SAlesByCountry2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
CountryName:string
MakeName:string
ModelName:string
Cost:integer
RepairsCost:integer
PartsCost:string
TransportInCost:integer
Color:string
SalePrice:double
LineItemDiscount:string
InvoiceNumber:string
SaleDate:date
CustomerName:string
SalesDetailsID:integer`
```

However, when I query the dataframe with the following sql code:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM SAlesByCountry2
WHERE YEAR(SAlesByCountry2.SaleDate) = 2018
```

I don't get any data, see below

[image]

Even though the year 2018 does exist when I query the whole dataframe

[image]

This is extremely puzzling as it should simply show the data, but I can't figure out why no data is appearing showing the date with the year 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ambiguity in your code. Below Statement does not change data type, it initialised value with today's date (so in that case there is no probability of getting data with year 2018)

```
SAlesByCountry2 = SAlesByCountry.withColumn("SaleDate", current_date())
```

I can see that in your existing `dataframe` the column `SaleDate` has a date format different than the date format `current_date()` return. `current_date()` return date format a `yyyy-MM-dd` but you have data with `dd/MM/yyyy` where **year** function does not work.

```
scala> df.withColumn("SaleDate",  current_date()).select(col("SaleDate")).show
+----------+
|  SaleDate|
+----------+
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
+----------+
```

**`year`** function work when you have data with date format as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
 scala> df.withColumn("SaleDate",  date_format(current_date(), "dd/MM/yyyy")).filter(year(col("SaleDate")) === "2019").select(col("SaleDate")).show()
+--------+
|SaleDate|
+--------+
+--------+
scala> df.withColumn("SaleDate",  date_format(current_date(), "yyyy-MM-dd")).filter(year(col("SaleDate")) === "2019").select(col("SaleDate")).show
+----------+
|  SaleDate|
+----------+
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
|2019-09-30|
+----------+
```

So for your problem's Solution, you need to change date format in column `SaleDate` as `yyyy-MM-dd` like below and confirm that `SaleDate` column has unique format for all rows.

```
 df.withColumn("SaleDate" , date_format(to_date(col("SaleDate"), "dd/MM/yyyy"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).filter(year(col("SaleDate")) === "2018")
```